# PopupControlExtender popup does not show up on the particular cell of the gridview

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I was working through creating popups on mouse over for cells in a gridview.
I am following the example [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/display-gridview-row-details-using-asp-net-ajax-popup-control)

The only difference being the example has just one cell that has the popup behavior.

For my case i have `19 columns` in the gridview which has about `8 columns` whose values have this behavior.

So i extended the example and added more `ajax:PopupControlExtender` elements and subsequently the other stuff as shown in the example.

When i run the code i see the popup always appearing at a fixed position in the `gridview row(say the second cell)` even if i have done the mouseover on the 19th cell.

**Edit :**

```
`protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
   { 
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     { 
  PopupControlExtender pce = e.Row.FindControl("PopupControlExtender1") as PopupControlExtender; 

  string behaviorID = "pce_" + e.Row.RowIndex; 
  pce.BehaviorID = behaviorID; 

  Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1"); 

  string OnMouseOverScript = string.Format("$find('{0}').showPopup();", behaviorID);
  string OnMouseOutScript = string.Format("$find('{0}').hidePopup();", behaviorID); 
  img.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", OnMouseOverScript); 
  img.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", OnMouseOutScript); }}
```

Above is the code within the row created method. 
Following is the code within the aspx file ,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
CellPadding="3" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" 
onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated"> 

  <Columns> 
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="Product ID" /> 
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" /> 

  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"> 
     <ItemTemplate> 

        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"      
        ImageUrl="~/images/magnify.gif" /> 

        <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server" 
           PopupControlID="Panel1" 
           TargetControlID="Image1" 
           DynamicContextKey='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' 
           DynamicControlID="Panel1" 
           DynamicServiceMethod="GetDynamicContent" Position="Bottom"> 
        </ajax:PopupControlExtender> 

     </ItemTemplate> 

  </asp:TemplateField> 
 </Columns> 
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" /> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Now this example is for displaying a popup on a single cell.
My question is what do i need to add to make another popup that shows up on the particular cell. i want the position of the popup to be exactly on the cell and not any other location.

Comment: you should post the code also, so that we can figure out if there is a mistake..!

Comment: Unfortunately i cant because of sensitivity. But it would be helpful how can the example in the link be extended to fit a grid with say two cells in a single row that show popup.

Comment: it's tough to imagine what sort of things is going with your code, I would suggest you to debug your code and check step by step that what is missing in your code

Comment: hmm i understand. i will try and post some more stuff.

Comment: yes, that would be great..!